# Окончание правильное?

Tags: окончания

**В Ялте демонтируют скандальные «Крошки-Лепешки».** Окончание правильное в слове **скандальные**? Речь идет о передвижных бистро.

Comment: А какие есть другие варианты окончаний на ваш взгляд?

Answer (score 1):

Окончание в слове **скандальные** правильное. Ведь во фразе имеются в виду именно **бистро** «Крошки-Лепешки», значит **демонтируют скандальные *бистро* «Крошки-Лепешки»**. Здесь по-другому написать и не получится. **Не** *скандальных* **же** *«Крошек-Лепешек» демонтируют.* То, что слово **бистро** во фразе отсутствует, ничего не меняет.